# Suggestions of tags and title edits by user NormalHuman - How to do it?

Tags: discussion, tagging, comment, specific-user

Almost $90$% of the questions I have seen from the time I have joined Maths.SE, I have noticed that the user **NormalHuman** suggests title edits, tag edits and question modifications almost instantly after the question pops up on the New Questions Tab and the language of the comments are almost the same.

*So my question is*: Does he do this separately for all the questions because it is surely very tiresome? Or does he use some kind of an alarm that posts this message to anyone asking a new question?

I want to know the trick for I want to use it too.

Comment: He's running a bot to do that.

Comment: There's some information about the bot [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/21681), with source on [GitHub](https://github.com/normalhuman/EarlyWarning).

Comment: He is a very fast typer.

Comment: In reality there are no normal humans. It's a ruse. It's a trap. It's a reverse Turing test. The only person to claim they are a "normal human" is in fact the internet incarnate. The ghost in the machine.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Reverse Turing Test???

Comment: @DanielFischer: Is running a bot for the purpose of telling new users off for not yet knowing everything (instead of actually making the question-improving edits that "Normal Human" exhorts the newbies to come up with on their own) something the moderator team approves of ???

Comment: Wow, people *will* complain about anything...

Comment: @HenningMakholm The current wording is "Consider adding a tag for a broader subject area to which the question belongs. This will improve the visibility of your question." If you think this comes across as rude, can you suggest a more polite version? Btw I have made over 5 times as many edits as you had.

Comment: @NormalHuman: If you know a better tag, you should edit it into the post instead of just teasing the poor newbie with, effectively, "there's a better tag for this post, but I'm not telling it what it is. Nyah nyah. Figure it out yourself". I don't think there's any way to make that message less rude by changing the wording -- the way to avoid being rude would be to _cease the rude behavior_, not to dress it up with irrelevant pleasantries.

Comment: Also, I fail to see how having made 5 times as many edits as I have justifies being rude to newbies. Why should having made a lot of edits entitle someone to that behavior? And even if it should, why would _my_ edit count somehow be related to the threshold of being-allowed-to-bite-the-newbies?

Comment: @HenningMakholm If we had reason to believe the purpose of the bot is "telling new users off", we would disapprove of that, and make it known to the user running the bot. But if the purpose is to provide some guidance to new (and not-so-new) users, we approve of the purpose. How the implementation will be judged is a different matter, we shall see.

Comment: @HenningMakholm : I remembered adding a new tags to a question, but the OP rollback the edit, and leave a comment like "It is rude to change my question without my approval". In some cases, editing the post might be considered more rude to some people.

Comment: Normal human is neither normal nor human. It is a Gnirut test.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I'm not privy to anyone's _purpose_, but what the bot DOES, empirically, is tell new users off for not magically knowing our tag system well enough, and thumbing its nose at them by not telling them what the right tag (according to the bot and/or its operator) would be. A possible but in any case unimplemented noble _purpose_ cannot excuse actual implemented rudeness IMO.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Empirically, someone tagging their question with "diophantine-equations" is capable of recognizing that "a broader subject area" is number theory, and adding a tag. I get a bunch of "thanks, fixed" responses every day from bot's operation, and this doesn't include the people who edit their question silently... Those who can't think of a tag tend to say so in their comment-reply -- at least they have someone to ping, because of that automatic comment. I get those replies and fix tags if still needed.

Comment: Normal Human is normal in that he is imposing a norm

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Not in being perpendicular to the tanget?

Comment: @NormalHuman As a recent new user and having seen newbie questions you have tagged I think it would come across clearer if the comment indicated it was automatically generated. Then newbies wouldn't feel confused and people would feel less offended as they know it isn't a human commenting.

Comment: @IanMiller do new users feel confused by the comment? This is meant as an honest question. I have not seen any myself and I think an example was not given either. // Without any solid evidence I'd speculate that marking it as auto-generated would take away from its effectiveness. This, and that there are a lot of comments that are a lot more difficult to make sense of than a polite request for additional tags makes me rather skeptical at that proposal.

Comment: @NormalHuman I am only based this off a sample size of one. It took me several questions before I came across someone explaining that Normal Human was a bot. Before then the bot's comment came across as a pushy moderator or something. I don't think you will find much evidence as most new people aren't going to try and argue with what looks like a figure of authority. Just my two cents.

Comment: @IanMiller I'll add a short notice at the end (have to deal with 600 character limit for somments). That said, plenty of users copy-paste [comment templates](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/), which is about as mechanical as the comment bot. Do you find the bot's comment more pushy than those?

Comment: @IanMiller I suppose your latest comment was in fact a reply to me. If the *only* problem is that somebody might not get it is auto-generated, I think I do not see the issue. As Normal Human remarked it is not the only comment that it not formulated by the user posting it. Some such functionality is even built into the site, and some more is supported since ages here on meta.  And again there are in my mind plenty of hand-crafted(?) comments that are harder to get and more pushy. For instance the  "What have you tried?" and variations on it. Frankly, suggesting extra tags is really a service.

Comment: @NormalHuman About a similar level. I think it was just that I saw a lot more of your comments than of others.

Comment: I find it truly odd that a user has been  allowed in effect to hack the site.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How is that, in any way, even remotely, "hacking"? This whole thing is starting to read like politics where party A would still manage to find a way to criticize party B if they somehow managed to cure cancer (because you know, oncologists would lose their jobs etc). Anything the "opposition" does is necessarily bad.

Comment: And anyone who believes that running scripts using the (public!) SE API is somehow discouraged or forbidden is invited to take a look at [stackapps](http://stackapps.com/). Please, everyone, take a step back: if SE displayed a warning (not an error) when a user used only one rare tag, or used one of several "bad" keywords in their titles, or displaymath in their titles, would you think this would be a positive or a negative change?

Comment: @AndréNicolas one can have mixed opinion on the merits of automated comments (indeed generally I am not a big fan of "canned" comments). However, mounting claims about "hack[ing] the site" and not even being able or willing to follow up on it to clarify is completely out of line in my opinion.

Comment: I find it very effective to copy-paste comments templates from the aforementioned post by Normal Human. Last month, I engaged in a spree of trying to help new users with that. It was very effective and had almost no complaints. I feel like a dumbed down, non-optimized bot. The bot is useful IMHO. Actually, I tried to make it run here... to no avail.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's not 90% of questions. The bot currently makes about <s>100</s> 70 comments a day, which is about 10% of new questions.  (I made it more conservative regarding the tag selection). The source is on [GitHub](https://github.com/normalhuman/EarlyWarning).

The comments are automatically deleted after 5 minutes, so the only way for you to see many of them is to open new questions soon after they are posted.  I suppose the repetitive language gets old if this is how you use the site, so I added some variety to the text, choosing a different wording at random.

*New*: the comments are now logged in [Normal chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30985/normal-chatroom), for those interested in the operation of the bot. This room is also a suitable place for feedback on bot's performance.

---

Aside on the effectiveness of the comments. Some are ignored. Many result in edits by OP. Some are also acknowledged by replies:

[image: img]

A few users also provided feedback on the algorithm, pointing out the instances where the bot's heuristic misfired. I modified it accordingly.

Comment: "The comments are automatically deleted after 5 minutes," I see why you might want to delete them eventually, but I find the time span too short and the situation can be confusing. I observed situations where an OP asked a follow up question and then the comment just went away. This could make an odd impression. Maybe either expand the span or do not remove it once there is a reply (if this is possible to detect reasonably easily).

Comment: The current version cancels the deletion if the comment received a reply containing a question mark. I think this makes more sense that keeping it every time there is a follow-up, because the follow-up is often "ok, did that", making the comment obsolete.

Comment: This seems like a good intermediate solution. Generally, I am impressed how effective this seems to be.

Comment: I find it quite annoying, especially since almost all of the instances that I’ve seen have been unwarranted.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for your feedback. I did change the algorithm after you pointed out some instances in which tags were in fact adequate. But since this apparently wasn't enough, I'll scale down the frequency of tag-based comments in general.

Comment: May I ask if the bot automatically inserts the soft-request immediately after a question is posted? Or does the algorithm know that no tags have been inserted? sometimes I see Questions where tags are visible but there has been no edit to the post, implying (I think) that the bot requests *further* tags.

Comment: @Bacon A question cannot exist without tags. The problem is that some tags are not very good for classifying the post (and arguably, shouldn't even exist). For example, if there is [tag:chain-rule] tag (a recently created tag with mere 25 questions), but no (calculus), (real-analysis), (multivariable-calculus), etc then the bot will point out that something is missing.

Comment: @NormalHuman: I should have said that I did notice that the specific instances on which I’d commented seemed not to have recurred, so the modification evidently did its job. But I felt awkward making making such comments very often.

Comment: Thanks for running the bot. I won't add my particular opinion on its functionality because my appreciation for people who create such content to better the site outweighs any small issues I would have with the algorithm.

Comment: I greatly appreciate the effort done by Normal Human, and think it is quite effective. That said, I don't think its use should be popularized. One bot is more than enough, and widespread use would lead to redundance and overwhelming artificialness.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Oh yes, I think one bot is quite enough. I've made the code available because this is what I always do, someone might want to use it on another site, or just learn from it how the API works.

Comment: Coincidentally, today another bot was discussed on SO: [Is TaggerBot a good idea?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309463)

Comment: ah *(autocomment)*... I was just about to ask if someone from the StackTeam implemented self-destroying comments...