# Question about Normal Human

Tags: discussion, support, specific-user

Why is the user **Normal Human** always annoys every body with tags? He is moreover not moderator or webmaster, so why has he the rights to always mention to every body that tags or some other stuff are not right? It's really really annoying! And often, the tags mentioned are much enough! If you ask a question about Galois theory, what other tag than [galois-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galois-theory) can be used? No one! Or if you ask a question about splitting field, which other tags can be consider? It's the only one! So why adding an other tag?  That's why I write a message here, to have answer about the rights of Normal Human, and to know if it disturbs also other people.

Comment: So only moderators can care about proper use on the site?

Comment: Nobody forces you to add more tags. But then again, you can't complain if your question does not get the proper exposure and remains unanswered.

Comment: You should add  a *more general tag* in addition, for example [tag:number-theory] or [tag:commutative-algebra], depending on focus.

Comment: I couldn't stop myself from adding the [tag:specific-user] tag to this post.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/21799), if not an outright duplicate.

Comment: If the only tag is [tag:galois-theory], there is no comment: this is an active tag with many questions. If the only tag is [tag:galois-cohomology], then a comment will point out that a broader tag would be useful in addition.

Comment: @NormalHuman: I hope you didn't take my post as an insult to you, I have nothing against you personally :-) It is just about your "auto-comment" (by the way, every body can program auto command or it you only ? Because I never see other auto-comment excepted yours).

Comment: Re: What other tag than [tag:galois-theory] can be used? This question is really to answer - just click on the tag and then look at the list of related tags in the sidebar.

Comment: Everything that needed to be said has been said already, but I feel to spend a couple of words in defense of the useful services @NormalHuman provides to the site. We all have the *right* to help moderation, and few of us do as an excellent job as (s)he does. Saying that's "annoying", or that "it disturbs" the users denotes, IMO, a lack of understanding of how the website works, or at least of how it should work.

Answer (score 16):

> Why is the user Normal Human always annoys every body with tags ?

Not everybody, mainly just those that do not use them efficiently.
They have automated this, which is why they are so prolific at it see [Suggestions of tags and title edits by user NormalHuman - How to do it?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21796/suggestions-of-tags-and-title-edits-by-user-normalhuman-how-to-do-it).

> He is moreover not moderator or webmaster, so why has he the rights to always mention to every body that tags or some other stuff are not right ?

It is correct they are neither webmaster nor moderator. But given that it is the case that every user with 2000+ points can change the tags of a question, it can hardly be considered as stepping beyond ones privileges when a user points out the tags could be changed.

> If you ask a question about Galois theory, what other tag than Galois-theory can be used ?

You can use in addition more general tags like [number-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory) maybe also [algebraic-number-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-number-theory) or [commutative-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commutative-algebra) or [field-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-theory) or still something else.

> Or if you ask a question about splitting field, which other tags can be 
>   consider ?

See above, and [galois-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galois-theory).

> So why adding an other tag ?

Various users filter by tag and only look at questions tagged with some specific tags. Mainly, they will chose rather large tags for this filtering. When you just use [splitting-field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/splitting-field) with its around 150 questions many users just might not see your question. With [galois-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galois-theory) this is slightly different, as it is rather large itself, but the reasoning still applies.

Thus it is really doing yourself a favor to add more tags, usually. But if you really do not want to just ignore the comment. Usually they will delete it soon enough.

Answer (score 11):

Some data for context. I looked up every comment of the "broader subject area" type made over the last 24 hours. There were 20 of those. Here is how the first revision was tagged (links go to that revision):

1. [bipartite-graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1534263/1)
2. [transcendental-numbers, independence](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1534313/1) -- although tag wiki of [independence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independence) tag says this isn't what it's for.
3. [spherical-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1534317/1) --  that one I added to "okay" tags
4. [orthogonality, bessel-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1534321/1) -- the latter should be used along with [special-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-functions), see [meta discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16695).
5. [ramsey-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1534422/1) -- no combinatorics tag, no reaction to the post.
6. [correlation, covariance](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1534436/1)
7. [learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1534563/1) ... we still have that tag, apparently it's somehow different from education and self-learning
8. [polygons](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1534680/1)
9. [operations-research](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1534729/1)
10. [calendar-computations](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1534841/1)
11. [prime-ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1534996/1)
12. [symbolic-computation](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1535001/1)
13. [balls-in-bins](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1535263/1)
14. [svd](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1535275/1)
15. [gaussian-elimination](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1535376/1)
16. [splitting-field](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1535479/1)
17. [mean-square-error](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1535487/1)
18. [curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1535764/1) ... no, it wasn't about geometry
19. [splitting-field](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1535810/1) again, by the same author. After this I added the tag to "okay" list not because I think it stands well on its own, but just to get this incident over with.
20. [maple](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1535848/1)

Having [galois-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galois-theory) as a sole tag would not generate a comment, so mentioning it a red herring.